# how to resolve the String Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, string, char

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].toString() != null) {
        char a = data[i].toString().charAt(0);

        if (a == a1) {
            if (distance(data[i], keyword) < 5) {
                Log.d("sjdhkshdjjjjjjjjjjjjjj", data[i]);
                dist.add(distance(data[i], keyword));
                sound.add(data[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's giving the exception on the line where access the first character from data[].tostring().

Comment: Instead of trying to describe what the line of code looks like, just tell us the exact line of code. Is it `char a2=data[5].charAt(0);`? Is it `char a1=input.charAt(0);`? Also, when asking for _free_ help at least take the time to indent your code properly.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what `data` looks like.

Comment: The way to resolve it is to stop going off the ends of the string (or array or list or collection). If you learn to use a debugger, you can step through the code and figure out what you're doing wrong more quickly than you can post a question to ask others to solve it for you.

Comment: `data[i].toString()` is empty. Read the exception message: it will tell you that the string length is zero.

Comment: char a = data[i].toString().charAt(0); this line giving exception and data[i].toString() not empty i checked it on start by condition

Comment: @MianHassan no, you checked if the string reference is `null`. Null and empty aren't the same thing: `"" != null` is false, but `"".isEmpty()` (or `"".length() == 0`) is true

Comment: @AndyTurner its also not working on isEmpty condition

Comment: @Mian Hassan If you do it like in the posted answers `data[i].toString().length>0)` (DJAM) or `!data[i].toString().isEmpty())` (a little cleaner by lesto) and also add `if(data[i] == null) continue; ` (from DJAM) your code will work. I don't really get the downvote of the question, as the question has just been posted. Shouldn't the poster be given a chance to edit the markdown-code or typos, if comments may point in that direction. As another tip to Mian: Always give the linenumber of the Exception and don't use log-Statements which print-output can't be seen.

Answer (score 0):

`data[i]` is probably an empty (but initialized) String, and you are trying to extrapolate its first character, thus the exception is rise.

the correct check would still check for data is not null, but also that contains at least one character;

`if (data[i].toString() != null && !data[i].toString().isEmpty())`

I would also avoid all this call to `toString()` and just call it one time an save the result in a temporary String variable; you are just trowing away unnecessary cycle, and in an multitasking system that result may be different between each call, making all the code get crazy. Basically it is just a good habit to learn to always do.

Answer (score 0):

Theses changes can enable you to avoid some exceptions

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i]==null) continue ; //Add this
        if (data[i].toString() != null &&  data[i].toString().length>0) {//Another change
            char a = data[i].toString().charAt(0);

            if (a == a1) {
                if (distance(data[i], keyword) < 5) {
                    Log.d("sjdhkshdjjjjjjjjjjjjjj", data[i]);
                    dist.add(distance(data[i], keyword));
                    sound.add(data[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```